# Can the Fireball spell be cast on yourself when swallowed by a creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, targeting

This question might be similar to the question ["Is it possible for a swallowed caster to cast Fireball outside of a Giant Toad?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141059/is-it-possible-for-a-swallowed-caster-to-cast-fireball-outside-of-a-giant-toad), but is not a duplicate.

In my situation, a homebrew monster swallowed the entire party. I planned in the story for the monster in question to take the party into its lair. But one of the players made a decision I did not expect: he cast *fireball* on his own character to try to pry open the creature's mouth at the expense of his own health.

As per the description of the [*fireball*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fireball) spell:

> A bright streak flashes from your pointing finger to a point you choose within range [...]

While the character was restrained and blinded, nothing realistically prevented him from pointing the finger towards himself... So I ruled in his favor, the blast happened, and the monster spat the party out. However, I'm curious whether there is any RAW or RAI that would make this kind of action impossible.

**Can the *fireball* spell be cast on yourself when swallowed by a creature?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Being Swallowed doesn't prevent attacks but may prevent spells that require Line of Sight.

Being Swallowed imposes the Blinded and Restrained conditions. Both of which say:

> Attack rolls against the [blinded or restrained] creature have advantage, and the [blinded or restrained] creature's attack rolls have disadvantage.

That's it. Nothing prevents attacks from being made or spells from being cast.

The blinded condition also states:

> A blinded creature can't see...

So a spell that says "choose a target you can see" or something to that effect then that won't work since you can't see. Something like Fireball, however, doesn't require Line of Sight, only Line of Effect.

> A bright streak flashes from your pointing finger to a point you choose within range...

Comment: And the giant toad thought that the chili peppers were hot ....

Comment: Don't you need access to the spell components, Vocal, Somatic and material?

Comment: It's worth noting that spells do what they say they do, however, and Fireball has no concussive force. It would not force a monster that's swallowed you to open its mouth.

Comment: @nick012000 I think having a blast of fire that burns the inside of your mouth would make you open your mouth, would'nt it ?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I would also argue that being inside a stomach would probably prevent vocalization and somatic components: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44790/what-conditions-prevent-a-caster-from-using-somatic-spells